# Qmail email address without hostname/domain name

Tags: unix, qmail

In our production a user sent an email to the following address "xxx" (Literally the email is address xxx). This address is within our companies organization (xxx@company.com.ph), I am being asked how it was sent without "@company.com.ph".

I told them it was probably the configuration of our SMTP server as I am sure the application I made is not appending "@company.com.ph" to mails without (hostName/domainName).

Our SMTP server is Qmail in a Unix box. Can anyone tell me what configurations  we could check to explain how this happened?

Unfortunately, I do not have a Qmail or Unixbox so I cant test it myself and I don't have access to our production servers so I could really use some help.

PS. Can anyone also give me the correct term for "@company.com.ph" is it the hostName/domainName?

**Checks Done**

1) According to the administrator - "defaultdomain" is set to "mail.company"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by default qmail will add defaultdomain to any recipient address missing the domain part.

@company.com.ph is the domain name part of the email address.

defaultdomain file by default is in /var/qmail/control directory as from documentation: http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#config-files